# Create PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, windows, pdf, ms-word

I need to create a PDF or Word file filled with contents from my database. Then the customer need to download that file. All this should happend when customer click on link.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) with much success to generate PDF files programatically using PHP.

And to generate word documents: http://www.phpdocx.com/ (this is a paid solution).

Answer (score 5):

Try TCPDF

http://www.tcpdf.org/

But google could have told you that

Comment: Google told me that by bringing me to this thread, so...

Answer (score 3):

[dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) is your best bet

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example: [html2pdf](http://www.html2pdf.fr/en/example). It's heavy library but seems to have very advanced functionality.

[dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) is a light library but it lacks a bit unicode support.

If you have access to the server maybe it would be better to install the [PECL PDF](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.installation.php) library. But I never used so cannot tell you if it's good

Answer (score 0):

Got one more: [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Hello World:

```
<?php
 require('fpdf.php');

 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
 $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Taken from: [FPDF Tutorial 1](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[wkthmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is really THE ONLY solution that worked for me that could produce what I call acceptable results. Still, some minor modifications to the CSS had to be made, however, it worked really well when it comes to rendering the content. All the other packages are really only suitable if you have a rather simply document with one basic table etc. No chance to get them to produce fair results on complex docs with design elements, css, multiple overlapping images etc. If complex documents are in game - do not spend the time (like I did) - go straight to wkhtmltopdf.

Take a look at my own question and solution in this post [HTML2PDF in PHP - convert utilities & scripts - examples & demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910975/pdf2html-in-php-convert-untilities-scripts-examples-demos)